# Pass var into wp function instead of direct string text

Tags: variables

Looking to replace static string text in this function with dynamic text from a var.

Current model:

```
  comments_number( 'no responses', '1 response', '% responses' );
```

Ideal Outcome (code guess):

```
  comments_number( '$no_responce_text', '1'.$responce_text, '%'.$responce_text );
```

I am sure this is an easy php question but stumped here.

Any help would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
comments_number(
   $no_responce_text,
   sprintf('1 %s', $responce_text), 
   sprintf('%% %s', $responce_text)
);`
```

Use [get_comments_number](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) if you want it properly localized.

Comment: There is one issue is with the last part, it is only outputting 2s (2 being a number greater than 1). Any thoughts on how to output the text with it? Does it have to do with the two %?

Comment: yes, the first %s needed to be escaped, fixed it.